# Mostrar una cadena string después de presionar Submit

Tags: php, html5

Quiero mostrar una cadena de caracteres hasta que se presione el botón Submit, pero actualmente antes de presionar el botón Submit ya me muestra una parte de la cadena que quiero mostrar. Ustedes pueden guiarme en decirme que estoy haciendo mal? De antemano muchas gracias por cualquier colaboración, les dejo el extracto del código:

Fecha de Inicio (yyyy-mm-dd): 
        " />
        
        
        Fecha Final (yyyy-mm-dd):          
        " />
        
        
        ID del producto: 
        " />

```
<?php 
    $fecha_inicio=$_POST['venta_productox_wc_fecha_inicio_value'];
    $fecha_final=$_POST['venta_productox_wc_fecha_final_value'];
    $id_producto=$_POST['venta_productox_wc_id_producto_value']; 

    if (count($_POST>0)) {
        $shortcode_generado = '[VentasProducto date_from="'.$fecha_inicio.'" date_to="'.$fecha_final.'" product_id="'.$id_producto.'"]';
        print_r($shortcode_generado);               
    }                   
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `onclik` en el `input` para que se ejecute una `funcion` que muestre el mensaje que necesites.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('mensaje').innerHTML = "enviando";
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
<span id="mensaje">sin enviar</span>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!